# Something like \enumerate, but with custom numbers at each \item

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

I'm doing homework from a particular book, and each question is numbered after the page number and the question number. For example 52.2, 52.9, 53.13, etc. (Note that they are not sequential.)

How do I do something that will work like the `enumerate` environment, but instead of 1. 2. 3., etc. at each `\item`, I put a custom number?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You could simply use the optional Argument of `\item`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item [2.9] Foo
    \item [53.2] Bar
    \item [69.11]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I hope that’s what you wanted to do …

Comment: Thanks. Strangely enough, I wasn't aware of the itemize function :O ... useful!

Comment: That's what I usually do, but the alignment works the other way I expect it to and I often have to fix it by defining my own lists. Any other means to do it?

Comment: @Francois: Please post a separate question with a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows the problem.

Comment: You can also do this using the `enumerate` environment (that is, in this instance, `itemize` and `enumerate` can be interchanged). Also, from a terminology perspective, these are environments.

Comment: If I do this with something long like [Question], the allignment gets messed up. However this is fixed if I change the environment to "description"

Comment: @geo909: This is because the labels, which is “Question” in your case, have a fixed width. If you have such list `{description}` seems to be more appropriate. You can also increase the label width e.g. by using the `enumitem` package.

Comment: But this way, the \ref command does not show the correct label. How should we fix this?

Comment: I guess this is impossible since `{itemize}` doesn't save any labels by default … maybe you ask a new question referring to this on ;-)

Comment: Is it possible to label them with the numbers inside?

Comment: What do you mean with “numbers inside“. I suggest you post a follow up question and link to this one.

Answer (score 32):

The genuinely insane way to do this is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\wackyenum}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@wackyenum\csname c@#1\endcsname%
}

\newcommand*{\@wackyenum}[1]{%
  $\ifcase#1\or52.2\or52.9\or53.13\or42%
    \else\@ctrerr\fi$%
}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\wackyenum}{\@wackyenum}{53.13}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\wackyenum*]
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This allows you to define an arbitrary list of numbers that the the enumeration will cycle through. This has the (very minor) advantage of having the spacing behave a little better. This is basically how a lot of things are done in the [`moreenum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moreenum) package. The [documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moreenum/moreenum-doc.pdf) explains the procedure.

Answer (score 18):

Depending on *how much* "non-sequential" your numbers are, and how much you need a quick & dirty solution instead of something with polish and automatism, you might get along with `\addtocounter` and some ad-hoc-ery involving the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=52.\arabic*,start=2]
\item Answer % 52.2
\addtocounter{enumi}{6}
\item Answer % 52.9
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=53.\arabic*,start=13]
\item Answer % 53.13
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

With a bit more work, you could make the page number (52, 53) into a counter of its own and wrap it all into a re-useable environment definition, but I think this gives you the idea of it all.

Answer (score 6):

Building up on Seamus's insane answer, here is how to do the same in ConTeXt.

```
\defineconversion[insane][52.2, 52.9, 53.13,42]

\starttext
\startitemize[insane]
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 4):

To get automatically the page number you can do as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,refcount}
\newcounter{qcount}
\newenvironment{questions}
  {\refstepcounter{qcount}\label{qcount\theqcount}%
   \begin{itemize}[label=\protect\getpagerefnumber{qcount\theqcount}.\protect\qcountnum]}
  {\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\qitem}[1]{\def\qcountnum{#1}\item}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\qitem{2} A
\qitem{25} B
\end{questions}

\newpage

\begin{questions}
\qitem{3} C
\qitem{7} D
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

At each `questions` environment a new label is generated, so we can use it for numbering the questions. The `\qitem` command wants as argument the question number. Since the mechanism exploits the `\label`-`\ref` system, two runs of `latex` are needed.

Answer (score 3):

In modification of egreg's solution you may use package perpages to have enumeration per page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{enumi}
\renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\theperpage.\arabic{enumi}}
\newcommand*{\nitem}[1][]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\else\setcounter{enumi}{\numexpr #1-1\relax}\fi
  \item
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter\@whilenum\value{page}<100\do{% demonstration of 99 pages
  \lipsum[\thepage]
  \begin{enumerate}
  \nitem A
  \nitem[7] B
  \nitem[19] C
  \nitem \lipsum[\thepage]
  \nitem D
  \end{enumerate}
  \newpage
}
\end{document}
```

Instead of redefining theenumi you may redefine `\labelenumi`:

```
\renewcommand*{\labelenumi}{\theperpage.\theenumi}
```

The difference is that `\label`/`\ref` will reference the number without page.