# How to number equations and floating materials by page number

Tags: floats, equations, numbering

I am somewhat intrigued by question [Something like \enumerate, but with custom numbers at each \item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29850/something-like-enumerate-but-with-custom-numbers-at-each-item/29904), which mentions a book where each question is numbered by its page number and the question number.

That question is about manual numbering of list items, but how would one go about making each **equation** be **automatically** numbered by its page number + a sequential number for each page. For instance, the first equation on page 50 would be numbered 50-1 and the second 50-2, while the first equation on the following page would be numbered 51-1.

Also, how can one extend this to cover floating material too, i.e., figures and tables. I’d prefer a numbering where each type of material (equation, figure, table) has a separate counter, so the first equation, the first figure and the first table on page 50 would all be numbered 50-1. (One would of course disambiguate between them by referring to ‘Equation 50-1’, ‘Figure 50-1’ and ‘Table 50-1’.)

For anyone wanting to have a go at this problem, here’s a simple example document you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\def\bodytext{

\begin{equation}
 2 + 2 = 4
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 e^{\pi i} = -1
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
First figure.
\caption{Figure caption one.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
Second figure.
\caption{Figure caption two.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[htbp]
First table.
\caption{Table caption one.}
\end{table}
}

\bodytext
\lipsum
\bodytext
\lipsum
\bodytext

\end{document}
```

By the way, I’m not sure ‘50-1’ is the best formatting to use. Other alternatives I can think of are (50-1), 50.1, 50(1) and 50a, and I actually think I prefer the last one. Any comments on this? (If so, please post them as comments, not answers.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting from the [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-oddpage):

> [T]he output routine is asynchronous, and (La)TeX will usually process
> quite a bit of the “next” page before deciding to output any page. As
> a result, the `page` counter (known internally in LaTeX as `\c@page`) is
> normally only reliable when you’re actually *in* the output routine.

In other words, don't use the `page` counter for the task at hand. Instead, use the [perpage](http://ctan.org/pkg/perpage) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{equation}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theperpage--\arabic{equation}}
\MakePerPage{figure}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\theperpage--\arabic{figure}}
\MakePerPage{table}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\theperpage--\arabic{table}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\def\bodytext{

\begin{equation}
 2 + 2 = 4
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 e^{\pi i} = -1
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
First figure.
\caption{Figure caption one.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
Second figure.
\caption{Figure caption two.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[htbp]
First table.
\caption{Table caption one.}
\end{table}
}

\bodytext
\lipsum
\bodytext
\lipsum
\bodytext

\end{document}
```

Here's an example of what might happen by simply using the `page` counter (modified from Werner's answer) -- the first equation on page 2 is incorrectly labelled (1--4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\counterwithin*{equation}{page}% equation counter is reset with every page counter reset
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thepage-\arabic{equation}}% page-equation
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\lipsum[4]

A short paragraph.

Another short paragraph.
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\lipsum[5]
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\lipsum[6]
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\lipsum[7]
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use page counter *if* you do it inside \AtBeginShipout, because there you are inside the output routine - see my answer.

Comment: Nice! Much more reliable.

Comment: The first solution works even if one equation is at the start of the page contrary tpo the secund one. To see that, put one empty line after each `\lipsum` calls, and two before.

Answer (score 1):

**Caveat**: The following method is inferior to options provided by (say) the [`perpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/perpage) or at the page shipout routine, as suggested by the other answers.

---

Here is the basic idea for counters of equations.

Use the [`chngcntr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) to specify a `<master>` counter for a `<slave>` using:

```
\counterwithin*{<slave>}{<master>}
```

Then you can redefine how the `equation` counter is printed using

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thepage-\arabic{equation}}%
```

Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\counterwithin*{equation}{page}% equation counter is reset with every page counter reset
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thepage-\arabic{equation}}% page-equation
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\lipsum[5]
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\lipsum[6]
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\lipsum[7]
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The same for the `figure` and `table` environment:

```
\counterwithin*{figure}{page}% figure counter is reset with every page counter reset
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thepage-\arabic{figure}}%
\counterwithin*{table}{page}% table counter is reset with every page counter reset
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thepage-\arabic{table}}%
```

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was added for dummy text.

---

It is not actually necessary to use the `chngcntr` package, since LaTeX does provide

```
\@addtoreset{<slave>}{<master>}
```

which requires the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` escaping pair. At this point it may just be personal preference. See the TeX FAQ entry on [Master and slave counters](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-addtoreset).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to redefine your prefix when you ship out the page.  Here is how:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\eqprefix}{1-}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipout{\gdef\eqprefix{\arabic{page}-}\setcounter{equation}{0}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\eqprefix\arabic{equation}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:first}
  a=b
\end{equation}
\newpage
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:second}
  b=c
\end{equation}

From equations~(\ref{eq:first}) and~(\ref{eq:second})  we get:
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:third}
  a=c
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not work well with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) due to setting the equation counter to `0`, right?

Comment: No, for compatibility with hyperred we need to do slightly more work...