# Counting number of equations in a page

Tags: pdftex, counters

Is there a way to count the number of equations (or other counted items) in a page and display it in the header? I am having trouble with keeping correct count when the page breaks and I'm not using `\newpage`. Actually, `\thepage` also is broken and displaying the wrong page number when it's in the body of the document.

I'm currently working on the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{everypage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcounter{CurrentPageCounter}
\newcounter{CurrentEquation}[CurrentPageCounter]
\lhead{Page \theCurrentPageCounter{}, equations on page: \theCurrentEquation{}} % not working

\newcommand{\addequation}{\stepcounter{CurrentEquation}}
\AddEverypageHook{\stepcounter{CurrentPageCounter}}
\chead{\today}
\rhead{Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\cfoot{}
\begin{document}

Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:
\[ 1 != 0 \]
\\
\vspace{50em}
\\
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:
\[ 1 = 1 \]
\newpage
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:
\[ a > 0 \]
\end{document}
```

On an updated system, this gives output like

```
Page 0, equations on page: 2   March 31, 2021   Page 1 of 3


   Equation 1 on page 1:
                                1! = 0
Page 1, equations on page: 0   March 31, 2021   Page 2 of 3


Equation 2 on page 1:
                                1=1
Page 2, equations on page: 1   March 31, 2021   Page 3 of 3


   Equation 1 on page 3:
                                a>0
```

but it should have "equations on page: 2" for the first page and "equations on page: 1" for the second.

Update:
With Willie's changes I have the following issue where the header reports the incorrect count:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{perpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcounter{CurrentEquation}
\MakePerPage{CurrentEquation}
\lhead{Page \thepage{}, equations on page: \theCurrentEquation{}} % not working, appears to update after the third equation

\newcommand{\addequation}{\stepcounter{CurrentEquation}}
\chead{\today}
\rhead{Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\cfoot{}
\begin{document}

Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 != 0 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ 1 = 1 \]
\newpage

Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:\[ a > 0 \]
\end{document}
```

The output looks something like

```
Page 1, equations on page: 3   March 31, 2021   Page 1 of 3


   Equation 1 on page 1:
                                1! = 0
Equation 2 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 3 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 4 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 5 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 6 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 7 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 8 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 9 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 10 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 11 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 12 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 13 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 14 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 15 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 16 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 17 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 18 on page 1:
                                1=1
Page 2, equations on page: 5   March 31, 2021   Page 2 of 3


Equation 1 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 2 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 3 on page 1:
                                1=1
Equation 4 on page 2:
                                1=1
Equation 5 on page 2:
                                1=1
Page 3, equations on page: 1   March 31, 2021   Page 3 of 3


   Equation 1 on page 3:
                                a>0
```

Comment: Using your MWE, I get the proper number of equations listed on each page.  However, I get a page-number count that is off by one.  However, I can fix your page issue by not using `CurrentPageCounter` and just using `\thepage`, which is already provided by LaTeX.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Would an old version change the AddEveryPageHook to make it run after the page is done being processed? I'm using the version from Alpine Linux, but it doesn't have some of the new Fall update stuff so I'm still using the obsolete everypage package.

Comment: It is possibly a version issue.  My version is `everypage 2020/10/17 R2.0b`

Comment: My log has `Package: everypage 2007/06/20 1.1 Hooks to run on every page` in it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It looks like that was only one of my problems. Running it on an updated Gentoo gives the correct results for the example, but if I separate the two equations on the first page with enough content (a bunch of `\\` to make them go on different pages) it counts both equations on page 1, zero on page 2, and 1 on page 3.

Comment: I would recommend you edit your question to provide an example that actually exhibits the problems (even with an up to date installation).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I have updated the question with the current output (new page issue without `\newpage` command to break the page).

Comment: Let me make sure I understand your issue: you are asking about essentially a page breaking problem, where if the equation being typeset is near a page boundary, you can run into off-by-one errors for the preceding and following page. If so: this is a hard problem to solve, since TeX has to process the code before deciding that it doesn't have enough space on the page to print it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{perpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcounter{CurrentEquation}
\MakePerPage{CurrentEquation}

\makeatletter
\def\pp@pagectr#1#2#3#4{\@ifundefined{c@pp@a@#1}{}{%
    \addtocounter{pp@a@#1}\@ne
    \expandafter\pp@labeldef\expandafter
      {\number\value{pp@a@#1}}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
      \@ifundefined{c@nu@pp@peq@#3}{\newcounter{nu@pp@peq@#3}}{}%
      \stepcounter{nu@pp@peq@#3}}
      \newcommand\showPageTotal[1]{\csname thenu@pp@peq@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\lhead{Page \thepage{}, equations on page: \showPageTotal{\thepage}}

\newcommand{\addequation}{\stepcounter{CurrentEquation}}
\chead{\today}
\rhead{Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\cfoot{}
\begin{document}

Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:
\[ 1 != 0 \]
\\
\vspace{50em}
\\
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:
\[ 1 = 1 \]Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:
\[ 1 = 1 \]Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:
\[ 1 = 1 \]Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:
\[ 1 = 1 \]
\newpage
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:
\[ a > 0 \]
\end{document}
```

This still uses `perpage` (see below); but now the header should be guaranteed correct, at least it should be as correct as `perpage` is.
Instead of relying on the value of `\theCurrentEquation` to be correct at ship-out, here we tap into the guts of `perpage` and piggy back a count.

1. `perpage` uses a `label`-like mechanism to locate the page numbers of the counters being stepped, and writes that information to the `.aux` file. This gets loaded at `\begin{document}` and allows it to compute how to match from the values of the `CurrentEquation` counter to the "per-page" values to be displayed.
2. Each time the `CurrentEquation` is stepped a line is written to the `.aux` file with, among other things, the absolute page number that it corresponds to.
3. So the code above patches the `\pp@pagectr` command that gets used, so that each time it is called, a per-page total counter is increased. (Downside: this will create a new counter per page.) This means that at the end of `\begin{document}` the per-page total count is already available, after the second compilation.
4. We also define a `\showPageTotal` command to display the information.

Caveats: the code will need a bit modification if you have more than one "PerPage" counter that you want to track totals of. Currently it just counts everything that shows up on each page. Modifying it to separate streams is not too hard.

---

TeX's page output is asynchronous from its processing of the input, and so trying to manually peg pages is *difficult*. So instead of doing it yourself, let someone else do it for you. Use the [`perpage` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/perpage):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{perpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcounter{CurrentEquation}
\MakePerPage{CurrentEquation}
\lhead{Page \thepage{}, equations on page: \theCurrentEquation{}} % not working

\newcommand{\addequation}{\stepcounter{CurrentEquation}}
\chead{\today}
\rhead{Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\cfoot{}
\begin{document}

Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:
\[ 1 != 0 \]
\\
\vspace{50em}
\\
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:
\[ 1 = 1 \]
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:
\[ 1 = 1 \]
\newpage
Equation \addequation{}\theCurrentEquation{} on page \thepage{}:
\[ a > 0 \]
\end{document}
```

The `perpage` package uses the `\label` mechanism behind the scenes, and so requires multiple passes for things to converge if they sit near page boundaries.

(Notice that the page number of the first equation shown on page 2 is incorrect, this is because when `\thepage` was processed it was still on page 1. But the `CurrentEquation` counter reports the correct values now. If you also want to access the current page number for real, the `perpage` package also provides the `\theperpage` command.)

Comment: (Credit: what you are doing is a lot similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33689/how-to-number-equations-and-floating-materials-by-page-number), from which this answer was taken.)

Comment: It looks like this is mostly working, but the header with the count can get off. I'll add to the bottom of the question if I can make a small example.

Comment: Please see the update and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Wow that got really complicated.