# Use Greek alphabet as Footnote labels

Tags: fonts, footnotes

I'd like to use Greek letters as footnote symbols eg α,β...

There is a solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36105/268850 but I'd like to remove the ´ character.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The modern Greek numeral sign (*dexia keraia*, which I believe means something like "hornlike projection on the right") is stored in the macro `\textdexiakeraia`. You could write

```
\renewcommand*{\textdexiakeraia}{}
```

and this would eliminate the number sign from *all* Greek numerals. I would rather do it only for the footnotes (in case you need the "correct" numerals in other circumstances), and redefine `\textdexiakeraia` only locally:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={15cm,8cm}]{geometry}% only for smaller snapshot

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{{\def\textdexiakeraia{}\greektext\greeknumeral\c@footnote}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

First\footnote{One}, second\footnote{two}, third\footnote{three},
fourth\footnote{four},  fifth\footnote{five}, sixth\footnote{6},
seven\footnote{7},eight\footnote{8},nine\footnote{9},
ten\footnote{10}, eleven\footnote{11}, however: \textgreek{\greeknumeral{3}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou @campa, that works – tested in Overleaf. Could this be coded for YAML Frontmatter or should it be added to LaTeX template?