# Can footmisc do repetitive footnote markers?

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

I tried to provide an answer to [Use Greek alphabet as Footnote labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641544) about having Greek letters as footnote markers. Fortunately someone else gave an excellent answer while I was still working on mine.

My answer was based on the `footmisc`  package by the sorely missed Robin Fairbairns.

In this package you can define a set of footnote markers, as shown below, but it appears that there are problems if there are more footnotes than one has specified markers for.

```
% footnoteprob.tex  SE 641544   %%% CAN  GET THIS TO WORK FOR GREEK LETTERS
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}

\DefineFNsymbols{greek}%[text]
                {{\(\alpha\)} {\(\beta\)} {\(\gamma\)} {\(\delta\)} }
                
\DefineFNsymbols{english}%{text]
                {a b c d}
                \setfnsymbol{greek}
%                \setfnsymbol{english}

                \begin{document}
Some $\alpha$ text.\footnote{First}

More text.\footnote{Second}

More text.\footnote{Third}

More text.\footnote{Fourth}

More text.\footnote{Fifth}
    
\end{document}
```

produces a "LaTeX error: Counter too large" for the fifth footnote.

Perhaps I have not understood properly the `footmisc` manual. Is it possible for the `footmisc` package to provide repetetive footnote markers so that in the above MWE the  fifth footnote could be labelled with the first item in the list `\alpha` or `a`, and so on?

Comment: there is no user interface,  but you naturally could redefine the error command to restart.