# How can I create a Question/Answer format for reports?

Tags: enumerate

I would like to create a question/answer format to use on lab reports. What I would like to achieve is something like this:

**a. This is the first question (in bold)?**

This is the answer (it is indented and regular text).

**b. This is the second question (bold)?**

This is the answer (indented and regular text).

I have no idea where to start. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Do you know the document class [exam](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam)?

Comment: Hey! I know this document class but I was wondering if there was some good way of doing this on the document class article.

Comment: perhaps useful: [Something like \enumerate, but with custom numbers at each \item](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29850)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would define an *enumerate* list and create an *answer* environment:  consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{QandA}{\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries\alph*.]\bfseries}
                      {\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{answered}{\par\normalfont}{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\noindent%
\lipsum[1]
\begin{QandA}
   \item question one
         \begin{answered}
         this is my answer:  \lipsum[2]
         \end{answered}

   \item question two
         \begin{answered}
         \lipsum[3]
         \end{answered}
\end{QandA}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This gives you some flexibility in terms of how you format the questions and how you format the answers.  Notice that I kind of sledgehammer the **bold font**.  To counteract this, I call `\normalfont` inside the `answered` environment.

The `enumitem` package gives you a lot of room for controlling margins.
To get further indentation on both the left and right margins, you can write

```
\newenvironment{QandA}{\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries\alph*.,leftmargin=2em,rightmargin=2em]\bfseries}
                      {\end{enumerate}}
```

If you want a paragraph indent at the beginning of the answer, then rewrite the `answered` environment to be:

```
\newenvironment{answered}{\setlength{\parindent}{1em}\par\normalfont}{}
```

If you play with these suggestions, you'll find you have a lot of control over the look and feel of the `answered` environment.

By adding these changes to the MWE, you'll get something like:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I tested this and works flawlessly!, I have another question... is there a possible way of indenting inside the answers?

Comment: If you could explain what you mean by *indenting*, I'd be happy to do so.  Lest you think I'm being snarky, I'm asking for clarification since within the `enumerate` environment paragraphs are usually already indented.

Comment: Dont worry! What I mean by indenting is that the first line of every answer paragraph is indented. I know the paragraph is already indented but I was wondering if the first line can have 2 indentations. Thank you very much for the help!