# How to create enumerate environment with item number in the format (i,j)?

Tags: lists, enumerate

```
\begin{enumerate}[(i)] 
 \item
\end{enumerate}
```

This gives the items with roman numbering.
But I want to numbering in (i,j) format, i.e. I want my items numbered like (1,2),(1,1), (5,4) etc. What to do?

Comment: Wnat is *i* and what is *j*? What do they represent?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: natural numbers

Comment: With *one* list, why do you want *two* numbers?

Comment: @ Paul Gaborit: Want describe some properties on matrix entries of some Matrix.

Comment: Does `\item[(i,j)]` help?

Comment: @user31526 Do you use the ivironments description or itemize whit no automatic numeration items?

Comment: @HendrikVogt: No

Comment: @user31526: To be more specific, does `\item[(1,2)] ...`, `\item[(1,1)] ...`, `\item[(5,4)] ...` help? Just "tell" the `\item` what numbering you want.

Comment: Please also have a look at the "Related" bar: [Something like \enumerate, but with custom numbers at each \item](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29850) appears to have answers to your question (possible duplicate).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following MWE implements a `(i)` numbering/labeling system for first-level items and an `(i,j)` numbering/labeling system for second-level items. Here, `i` and `j` are arabic numerals.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{(\arabic{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{(\arabic{enumi},\arabic{enumii})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@enumii}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First level-one item 
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First level-two item 
  \item Second level-two item
  \end{enumerate}
\item Second level-one item 
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Still another level-two item 
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comments:

- If you don't wish to adjust the labeling style of the first-level items, just comment out (or delete) the instructions that reset `\theenumi` and `\labelenumi`.
- The instruction `\renewcommand{\p@enumii}{}` is there to let level-2 items be cross-referenced using the usual `\label` and `\ref` method. Because it contains a "special" character (the `@` symbol), the instruction has to be "wrapped" inside a pair of `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` instructions.

Answer (score 8):

I always like to use the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) package for anything list-related; perhaps it is overkill in this case, but here's one way that it can be done.

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\arabic{enumi}{,}\arabic*)}
```

The `1` is for 'first-level', and the `2` is for 'second-level'.

[image: screenshot]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\arabic{enumi}{,}\arabic*)}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First level-one item 
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First level-two item 
  \item Second level-two item
  \end{enumerate}
\item Second level-one item 
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Still another level-two item 
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```