# Sort-of-a table by left indent

Tags: tables, indentation

I try to cerate kind-of-a table in latex. The screenshot below shows how it should look in the end. Using Microsoft Word, I just set the left indents and a tab accordingly.

[image: Sort-of-a table]

**How's the right approach to create a similar structure in LaTeX?**

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! What have you done so far? It is alwasy a good idea to add some code. - I think he following could be useful... '\newcommand*{\@wackyenum}[1]{%
  $\ifcase#1\or a\or c\or tyz\or42%
    \else\@ctrerr\fi$%
}' like [Something like \enumerate, but with custom numbers at each \item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29904/124842)

Comment: @Bobyandbob: I didn't try anything so far, because I don't know whether I should use something from enumerates or tables or manipulating the indents, or ... That's basically the question.

Comment: How long is this table/list? Is it potentially longer than a full page?

Comment: @Mico: Yes, it could be very long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one out of many possibilities.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1cm,labelsep=2cm,leftmargin=!]
 \item[a] \lipsum[1]
 \item[bc] \lipsum[2]
 \item[d] \lipsum[3]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `leftmargin=1cm,leftmargin=!`?

Comment: @Skillmon As I wrote, that is one of many possibilities. Please see section 3.2 of the `enumitem` manual in case you are wondering about `!`. I have no information other that this should be "sort-of-a table", so I just posted one example.

Comment: I meant, that this is redundant. You're specifying the `leftmargin` to be 1cm wide, and afterwards say that `leftmargin` should be calculated from the `labelsep`. `labelsep=2cm,leftmargin=!` gives the same result.